# MySQL: Search for coincidences and differences in two tables

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to find matchs between two tables, but also need to display when there is no match.

**Table1:** id, dni_number, name, business_id

**Table2:** id, dni, business_id

I need to form a table like this:

| id | dni | name | business_id | is_match |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12365478 | John Doe | 15451 | 1 |
| 1 | 22365478 | Karen Doe | 23451 | 0 |

is_match meaning 1: it found the dni in table1 and also in table2, 0 for not match

The query should have a where condition to find matchs from certain business_id

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, (table2.dnu = table1.dnu) AS is_match 
FROM table1 
   LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.business_id = table2.business_id 
WHERE table1.business_id = xxx;
```

Comment: This works great without the WHERE condition, I need to add a WHERE business_id = xxx, and show those that have the same business_id but don't match the dni

Comment: I need to show both is_match 0 and 1

Comment: @CristianUhrig Edited the answer. Is it working for you now?

Comment: this way it repeats the info, and show the same dni as is_match 1 and 0, here is a picture of the result, I marked one as an example: https://imgur.com/a/XpXh081

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
tblA.id,
1 as is_match
FROM tblA, tblB
WHERE tblA.id = tblB.id

UNION ALL

SELECT
tblA.id,
0 as is_match
FROM tblA, tblB
WHERE tblA.id != tblB.id
```

Comment: When I add a where clause to only search from certain business_id (people share business_id, is not unique) it repeats the info, showing it as 0 and 1

https://imgur.com/a/RM7pMl4

Comment: but your question is: 1 - if it is in tbl1 and 0 if it is not in tbl2

Comment: You didn't read the full question then.
"The query should have a where condition to find matchs from certain business_id"

Comment: Your query works great without the where condition, but when I add it, it repeats the info like in the picture I left